# Search with pagination

Tags: php

I have this search with pagination, the search function is working fine and the pagination is also working fine but my real problem is that I don't know how to merge those two. Every time I try to search, the search result is showing but the pagination is not functioning normal. Please someone help me about this issue. I don't know where to start.

I have this code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("region_survey", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM municipality";




if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

$sql .= " WHERE province_id LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";

}

$query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());


?>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="">

Search:<input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search the table" />

</form>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//Include the PS_Pagination class
include('ps.php');

//Connect to mysql db
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$conn) die("Failed to connect to database!");
$status = mysql_select_db('region_survey', $conn);
if(!$status) die("Failed to select database!");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM municipality';



//Create a PS_Pagination object
$pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 15, 17);

//The paginate() function returns a mysql result set for the current page
$rs = $pager->paginate();
?>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Count total number of records after search
mysql_select_db("region_survey", $con);

if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);


$sql="SELECT * FROM municipality WHERE province_id LIKE '%$search_term%'";

}

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "Total Number: ";
echo $row;
?>


<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="resultTable">
        <tr>
          <th> <strong>ID</strong> </th>
          <th> <strong>Province ID</strong> </th>
          <th> <strong>Municipality Name</strong> </th>
        </tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

{
?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row["id"]; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row["province_id"]; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row["municipality_name"]; ?></td>
<td><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox"
id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></td>
        <td><a href="update.php<?php echo '?id='.$row['id']; ?>">Edit</a>        </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
   </table>    

   <?php
//Display the navigation
//echo $pager->renderFullNav();
echo '<div style="text-align:center">'.$pager->renderFullNav().'</div>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use limit and offset in mysql query when clicking the pagination links

Comment: how can i do that..can you give some example please because i'm just a begginer in php

Answer (score 0):

Pages will have URL like `example.com/search/term/?page=2` (or `example.com/search.php?term=xyz&page=2`, doesn't matter if you redirect URLs or not).

In PHP then will be something like:

```
$pagelimit = 10; // records per page
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1; // set current page
```

And `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` in your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM municipality 
        WHERE province_id LIKE '%$search_term%' 
        LIMIT " . ($page - 1) * $pagelimit . ", " . $pagelimit;
```

Comment: thank for the reply but where exactly should i  put that code??

Comment: @kierkier: I don't know what URL format you use in pagination now, just use there parameter `page=XX`. It should be simply. And the other two code samples put instead of the current `$sql = "..."` on line 78 in the code above.

Comment: $pagelimit = 10; // records per page
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)_$_GET['page'] : 1; // set current page

Comment: <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Count total number of records after search
mysql_select_db("region_survey", $con);

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
 
 $search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

$pagelimit = 10; // records per page
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)_$_GET['page'] : 1; // set current page

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM municipality 
        WHERE province_id LIKE '%$search_term%' 
        LIMIT " . ($page - 1) * $pagelimit . ", " . $pagelimit;


}

Comment: @kierkier: there was typo, `(int)$_GET['page']` instead of `(int)_$_GET['page']`. Follow the error messages, you should be able to find this typo yourself.

Comment: i can't figure out the error..

Comment: I GET IT..BUT THE PROBLEM IS WHERE EXACTLY SHOULT I PUT THAT CODE?

Comment: @kierkier: replace your current query by mine. Nothing more.

Comment: i've alredy done that but now the problem is that when i search the result is not displaying but the count is working

Comment: @kierkier: and really think I know where the problem can be with I don't know what you have in your PHP, in database etc.? SQL query which I gave you returns 10 results, 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, etc. due to `$_GET['page']`. I can't help you more.